# Exiting while loop on websocket module in Python with async code

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I have the following code that connects to websocket server and receives messages:

```
async def connect():
    async with websockets.client.connect('MYURI') as ws:
        LastUpdate = time.time()
        while time.time() - LastUpdate < 4:
            LastUpdate = time.time()
            await ws.recv()
        print('Not receiving messages')
```

I want this code to exit the while loop and close the task its running into when it didn't receive messages for more than 4 seconds.

I tried to do replicate this scenario by disconnecting my internet connection while running the script, but the problem is that when the connection doesn't receive messages for more than 4 seconds, it will wait more and then close the whole code with a timeout error, so it doesn't exit the while loop. Is there any way to do thsi? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: We use `Sanic` for websocket server https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/websocket.html

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044426/close-a-task-in-python-based-on-condition). If it is not, please explain the difference and we'll reopen the question.

Comment: I made this question before the other one, but this one was too confusing and less specific, so i decided to make a new question, it's not a problem to close it! Thank you!