# Close a task in Python based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm using AsyncIO and the Websockets module to create two concurrent tasks in Python, each one connects to a websocket server and receives messages.

I'm trying to create a system where, when a task did not receive messages for more than 4 seconds, it must close the connection and the task, but i'm having an hard time figuring that out. Can anyone help me out on this?

Here is what i tried:

```
async def connect(URI):
    async with websockets.client.connect(URI) as ws:
        LastUpdate = time.time()
        while time.time() - LastUpdate < 4:
            LastUpdate = time.time()
            await ws.recv()

        print('Not receiving updates anymore')
                
async def main():
    Tasks = [asyncio.create_task(connect('URI1')), asyncio.create_task(connect('URI2'))]

    await asyncio.gather(*Tasks)
```

Here, `main` creates two concurrent tasks and runs both of them. `connect` takes care of connecting and receiving messages. What i tried to do is to break the while loop when the last update was more than 4 seconds ago, but that didn't work since the loop doesn't get broken.

Comment: Is `URI1` a typo in this line? `async with websockets.client.connect(URI1) as ws:`

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for):

```
async def connect(URI):
    async with websockets.client.connect(URI) as ws:
        while True:
            try:
                msg = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), 4)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                break
            # do something with msg

        print('Not receiving updates anymore')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! In this case how can i access the content of the message? I tried to add print(await ws.recv()) where you placed #do something with msg, but it gave me an error about wait_for being never awaited

Comment: Alright, so to access the message ws.recv() will do it. As for the error, i think the problem was that it should be msg = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), 4)

Comment: @JayK23 The content was intended to be in the local variable `msg`, but as you noticed, I forgot to put an `await` in front of `asyncio.wait_for()`. I've now amended the answer.

Comment: This is very clear. In a scenario where i would like my code to retry to connect indefinitely, after the while loop is exited, what would i do? I currently did this with an higher level while loop, i placed it right after async def connect (..). It seems to work but i don't know if there are better ways to do it. I know it's beyond the question, i'll create another one if i need to. Thanks again a lot!

Comment: @JayK23 An outer loop (possibly situated in the caller of `connect`) is a reasonable solution, yes.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple ways to do this.

1. You can set a timeout in the package you are using within the async routine.
2. You can use asyncio and terminate tasks when they reach a timeout.
3. You can use non-blocking sockets for all operations, and not use asyncio at all, but use select() or poll(). This is very efficient but a lot more complex.

I would go in this order, the first one being the easiest and most preferred in most cases. Websockets seem to handle timeouts: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/29c15714ac9f5272e1adefc9c99b83420b409f63/websocket/_socket.py#L99

You probably want to set a timeout on the socket. Generally this is done with https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

I suppose websockets expose this functionality somewhere though, but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Setting the timeout on the socket as implied by your second-to-last paragraph won't work because the OP is using websockets which don't expose the sockets used internally, and also because `socket.settimeout` only affects blocking sockets. (In fact using `settimeout` will even [_make_ the socket blocking](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts), so it cannot be used with asyncio.) Regarding #3, using non-blocking sockets and select/poll is precisely what asyncio does internally, so asyncio timeouts should be just as efficient as that.

Comment: @user4815162342 Clearly #3 refers to a case in which asyncio would not be used. You are right though, I probably should have added that setting the socket up for timing out should be done via the websockets library, if possible. I am not familiar with it, but I assumed, that since you can pass a socket in to wc.connect() via the "socket" option (https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/29c15714ac9f5272e1adefc9c99b83420b409f63/websocket/_core.py#L216) this should be done manually.

Comment: *Clearly #3 refers to a case in which asyncio would not be used* - I understand that, I was just pointing out that there is no reason for that approach to be any more efficient than just using asyncio in the first place, since it will end up doing the exact same thing on the kernel level.

Comment: Actually I don't think that is the case at all. Even though I haven't looked into the CPython interpreter in a couple years, last time I checked, doing this from Python for individual sockets was done rather inefficiently, calling select() on the single socket each time. You rolling your own non-blocking socket code and batching them up for poll/select/etc... will always be more efficient. This is only relevant though if you have thousands of sockets, and writing code like this is considerably harder and not very useful in this particular case.

Comment: *Actually I don't think that is the case at all* - You should then check the sources of asyncio and be pleasantly suprised because it definitely selects all file descriptors _en masse_. That's the whole point of modern event loop implementations like asyncio, and is just as efficient as a home-grown solution (if not more so).

Comment: Again, in case #3 you do NOT need asyncio.

Comment: As I said previously, I understand that and was referring to your incorrect assertion that such an approach would be _more efficient_ than asyncio. It wouldn't.